Error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'main::<lambda_1>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
I am learning to write lambda expression in cpp, Below is the code. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows.
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int k = 98;
  int l = 23;

  auto lm_add = [k,l](int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
  };

  cout << "addition using lambda : " << "cool" << lm_add << endl;

  return 0;
}

I want to return the answer for given variables.

The lambda is capturing k and l for no reason.  The output should invoke the lambda, lm_add(1,2).

Remember the first part of that comment: auto lm_add = [](int i, int j) { or did you want auto lm_add = [k,l]()  { return k + l; } the call with << lm_add() <<

cout << ... << lm_add  is attempting to print the lambda object itself which makes no sense here. In order to invoke the lambda and print the result you need to use lm_add(...).

Please clarify what you actually need the lambda to do: get 2 arguments in each invocation (these should be i,j), or capture 2 values once at the time the lambda is created (k,l) and always return their sum ?

This
auto lm_add = [k,l](int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
};

Initializes lm_add with a lambda expression. Behind the scenes the compiler generates an unnamed unique type with a call operator with the specified signature, ie taking two integers, and with members for the captures (also two integers). That type has no << operator to pipe it to an outstream. It can be called:
std::cout << lm_add(k,l);

However, it captures k and l for no good reason. Perhaps you want to either capture the variables so you can call it without arguments:
auto lm_add = [k,l]() {
    return k + l;
};

std::cout << lm_add();

Or not capture them an pass the argumetns:
auto lm_add = [](int i,int j) {
    return i + j;
};

std::cout << lm_add(k,l);


Thanks for explaining in details, Can you please share any references to understand topic  lambda in cpp, thanks in advance

Here is a good reference with examples: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
